# Domain Pointing

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I currently have the domain www.sellframe.com which contains a folder "leaseway"

I have another domain, called www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk

I want www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk to POINT to www.sellframe.com/leaseway

How would I do this? I only have a simple DNS manager with my host

I tried adding the record:

> leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk CNAME sellframe.com/leaseway
>
> *to leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk*

Im guessing this makes no sense as it doesnt work ahha, I have very little experience with this

Can someone be kind enough to spoon feed me the details. PS. I dont have access to a HTACCESS file or whatever or HT.CONF or whatever

Thanks Alot

**EDIT**

Hi guys, thanks for all your help so far, but Im still struggling.

To reiterate:

I DONT want to use iframes or HTML forwarding, Id like the domain to point directly to the folder "leaseway" so that www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk/index.php?page=vehicles would work.

**Here is the current DNS settings for www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk, does this look right or completely wrong to anyone?**

The top box reads "leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk CNAME sellframe.com"
The bottom box reads "www/leaseway A 66.98.136.44"

[image: "DNS SETTINGS"]

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want here is a single web page containing a frame set.

The frame set would contain only a single frame.

The frame would load: http://www.sellframe.com/leaseway

The URL on top would show: http://www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk and would never change.

Something like this:

```
<html>

<frameset rows="100%,*">
<frame src="http://www.sellframe.com/leaseway">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Place the above code in your http://www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk root folder and you should be good to go.

---

EDIT:

Another way to do it would be to set up your http://www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk normally and make the root/home directory be the "/leaseway" directory from your other domain.

You'd just have to modify your web server accordingly.

Comment: thanks, this is kinda how I already have it setup on www.leasewayvansales.co.uk but obviously it isnt ideal for SEO, this definitely not possible otherwise?

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have asked [the above question before](https://serverfault.com/questions/47361/domain-pointingp) using a different account.  :-)

Your question has already been answered by ray (this question) and David Mackintosh (previous question).  I'll just expand on their answers.

To recover from your current predicament, do as rob suggests -- reset your DNS settings back to their defaults.  Then, create the appropriate DNS records for `www.sellframe.com` and `www.leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk`.  You'll need something like ...

```
www.sellframe.com.          A     aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
www.leasewayvehicles.co.uk. CNAME www.sellframe.com.
```

Now configure your web server to support the two web sites at the one IP address.  (Apache calls them Virtual Hosts.)  How this is done will depend on the web server that you are using.  The basic idea is to configure your web server so that when a request is received for ...

- `www.sellframe.com` the web server will display the content from some directory on your server, say, `/var/www/www.sellframe.com`.
- `www.leasewayvehicles.co.uk` the web server will display the content from another directory on your server, say, `/var/www/www.sellframe.com/leaseway`.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirect on the server.

Comment: As I say, Im VERY new to this, this means nothing to me Im afraid!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You have to do this serverside.  On leasewayvehiclesales.co.uk you have to create a redirection (301) to the new server.  The other way to do this is with a proxy but that is messy.  If you don't have access to a simple .htaccess file, httpd.conf, or anything else on the server, you can't do anything.

Comment: I found a http/conf folder with nothing in it, can I just create a httpd.conf and put it in there?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do but you cant set CNAMES like that. CNAMES can only be domains to domains. One way to it is you can CNAME the 2 domains and make the root/home dir of sellframe.com /leaseway. The other better way ofcourse is setting a VirtualHost directive on Apache via htaccess or the conf which unfortunately u dont have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be thinking too hard on this one.  ;)

Most (all?) domain registrars, such as GoDaddy and Network Solutions, have an option to forward your domain name to any URL or domain subdirectory.  If you can create a CNAME record, then you can probably click a radio button somewhere else in the control panel to enable the domain forwarding.

EDIT: The link below shows how to set up domain forwarding through your registrar, ResellOne.  Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page to see the exact screen where you set up the forwarding; it's under the heading "Managed DNS: Domain Forwarding and Parking" and is the second-to-last screenshot on the page.

http://resellone.net/support/manageddns_demo.aspx

Comment: Phil: you should click the Rest button to reset DNS to the system default.  The CNAME and A records cannot be used this way.  What you need to look for is an option for "domain forwarding," which is probably on a different screen in the control panel.  If you're a direct customer of ResellOne, you should be able to configure this.  If your domain names are through a reseller who uses ResellOne, you should be able to ask that company to set up the forwarding fo ryou if it's not available in your control panel.